# Wordpiece Tokenization Model

Tags: nlp, tokenize, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

Can somebody tell me how exactly the wordpiece model work ? I am having some hard time trying to understand how exactly the wordpiece model is working. I understand the BPE that it is based on merging according the highest frequency pairs. After digging for hours on the internet and reading the paper. It is mentioned that in wordpiece we make the final merge according to what maximize the likelihood of the Language model we created.
How is this language model is created ? Is it created by Probability of Pair equal to Count of Pair / Total Count of Pairs or what ?
What i understand is that we want to measure which token pair minus separate tokens is the largest , like if we have "de" = 9 , "d" = 15 "e" = 12 and "th" = 10 , "t" = 12 "h"= 12 , then we choose to merge token "t" and "h" as its 10-24 > 9-27. Am i right ? Please somebody correct me